# Replace entire document in Bulk Operation Spring MongoDB

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot Version 2.1.0 and mongo driver version 3.8.2. I am not able to replace the entire document during bulk update operation.

It was working fine before upgrading to Spring Boot version 2.1.0. I was using ops.find().replaceOne() in spring boot 1.5.9

I tried BulkOps.updateOne.. But it is throwing Invalid Bson Name _id.

I tried dbObject.remove("_id"); But still getting the error with other fields.

```
BulkOperations ops = mongoOperations.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, A.class);
list.forEach(item -> {
Document dbObject = new Document();
converter.write(item, dbObject);
ops.updateOne(query(where("_id").is(item.getId())),Update.fromDocument(dbObject));
});
ops.execute();

Expected -- it should replace the entire document matching the ID.
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
final BulkOperations bulkOperations = 
mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED,A.class, A);

final Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(A.getId()));
bulkOperations.replaceOne(query,A);
bulkOperations.execute();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.